# How to insert Javascript into VBscript?

Tags: javascript, printing, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a block of VBscript that prints Report A and Report B. It calls window.print for Report A, then uses ActiveX to call on a PrinterHelperPrn.exe that can change the printer settings to landscape to print Report B. The problem is, that PrinterHelperPrn.exe can close a print dialog without being prompted-- so report B always ends up in the print que first. This is problematic because it makes the printer "landscape" and when Report A hits the printer, it also tries to print landscape.(Report A is supposed to be portrait, not landscape.)

- Note: PrinterHelperPrn.exe is Active X. I don't have access to the source code of the .exe that is fired. It's an old program, we can use it but we can't really change it. I've tried using the prn.Printpage to print Report A, but I can't seem to figure out what the URL should be-- I've tried a few things and they all make me lose my session and it ends up just printing the Login Page.
- Note2: I've tried the reverse, printing Report B with window.print...but the problem is you can't set printer orientation settings with Internet Explorer unless you use ActiveX.
- Note3: I thought about a Timer and even tried it-- but it usually just makes the script time out, even if I allow for an exceptionally long time for things to load. Furthermore, I can't guarantee a user will always click things within any arbitrary time I make a timer for.
- Note4: The program only has to work in Internet Explorer

**Report A** = Nightly Close Out

**Report B** = Profit Report

This is the original code with a bug in it:

```
document.all.divmenubar.style.display="none"
window.print 'Report A
document.all.divmenubar.style.display=""

        Dim strURL
        strURL = "<%="http://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & "/upfolder/printprofitreport.asp" & "?" & Request.Querystring & "&printdate=" & SpecialFormatDateTime(datCloseOutDate, vbshortdate) & "&StoreID=" & session("StoreID") %>"

        prn.SetDefaults
        prn.PrintPage 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5000, "", strURL 'Report B Prints
```

I have tried to change it to the following. However now **nothing** prints. When I take the javascript out of the vbscript the vbscript will run just fine-- but the second I add even just the javascript tags inbetween nothing will print anymore.

```
<script language="vbscript">
    Sub window_onload()

        document.all.divHeader.Style.Display = "None"

        'Hides the Menu, Prints the Nightly Close Out Report
        Dim isNightlyCloseOutPrinted 
        isNightlyCloseOutPrinted = false
        document.all.divmenubar.style.display="none"
        </script>

    <script language="javascript">
        window.print(); 
    window.onafterprint = function(){
   console.log("Testing...Hit the Javascript");}
   </script>

   <script language="vbscript">
    isNightlyCloseOutPrinted = true
    document.all.divmenubar.style.display=""
'More Code blah blah
```

How do I use Javascript inside of VBscript like this?

**I can do these, but they would take forever:**

- Make these PDFs so I can control the printing orientation.
- Learn about Active X and try to make a "new" version of
  PrinterHelperPrn.exe. Looking at some of the code for the other
  Active X controls we have, I can only guess this would take quite a
  while.

Comment: you can't change the script engine on-the-fly in that way, you must separate Vbscript from JScript, still you can put both scripts in the same page, but you need to call it with a method. This way has his own problems, like the execution order beetween <script> blocks:
__1st__ <script> blocks with __non-default script languages__ (in your case, JScript), __2nd__ <script> blocks with the __default script language__ (in your case, VBScript), __3rd__ <% ... %> blocks,  using __the default script language__ (in your case, VBScript).

Comment: I understood you are trying to use VBScript to access the ActiveX object, just in case, you don't need to use VBScript for that, you can use Javascript too (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Rafael, that's pretty much the answer for me-- "You can't just change it on the fly like that." If you make that an answer I will mark it as correct to help others a bit more.

Comment: Also sorry if anyone thinks this is very "this will only help one person", I was just trying to give context as to why I was trying to put Javascript inside of VBScript in the first place.

Comment: See: http://phrogz.net/tmp/serversidejsandvb.html on how to mix js and vbs maybe that's something you can use

Comment: sorry i do not get your question? did you describe the bug you have in the vbscript solution? we are talking about Client side vbscript and JavaScript right?

Comment: I've edited my post to make it a little clearer. As far as I understand this would be considered client-side. I'm still new to these scripting languages so I may be misunderstanding that.